# Angular onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Angular newbie here. I was wondering if it's possible to use the *$http* service to call a function upon any ready *state/status* change and not only upon *success/failure*. 
In terms of code, it would be the equivalent angular code to the following **JS** code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhr.readyState < 4 && xhr.status != 200)
        alert('Loading');
}
xhr.open...
xhr.send...
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) doesn't mention anything like that. The only thing I haven't tried yet is looking inside `$http.pendingRequests`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `$httpProvider` and it's interceptor. There's a good video on the topic at [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-angularjs-interceptors-with-http).

Comment: Yeah interceptors are quite powerful, http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/01/02/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget/

Answer (score 1):

That event in not used in 1.3+ anymore and is not exposed and only uses state 4 in 1.2.

The only way to do something like that (if you really wanted to) would be to replace or decorate $httpBackend...

See `createHttpBackend()` in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that I've used successfully is to call $scope.$apply() after what would otherwise be the $http call:

```
// using $http
var promise = $http.get(url).then(success, ...); 

// without $http
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     success: function() {
         success();
         $scope.$apply(); // if you'd used $http, this would be unnecessary
     },
     ...
});
```